# Rails 3 trouble with SQL server 2000 legacy database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, jdbc, jruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails3 talks to SQL Server 2000-----ActiveRecord::JDBCError: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356218/rails3-talks-to-sql-server-2000-activerecordjdbcerror-row-number-is-not)

I know ROW_NUMBER function does not exist in SQL SERVER 2000, but the real question is: is there any workaround for this problem b/c I would like to use Rails 3.

I am trying to get a Rails 3 application to work with SQL Server 2000 using activerecord-jdbc-adapter.  this is the error:

> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function
>   name.: SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
>   [pencils].id) AS _row_num, [pencils].* FROM [pencils] WHERE
>   [pencils].[id] = 1) AS t WHERE t._row_num BETWEEN 1 AND 1

Constraints: upgrading database not an option.  using Rails 2 I would rather not.

I have heard of creating a temp table with an IDENTITY COLUMN, but I fail to see how that would help b/c it seems like Active Record JDBC is trying to use ROW_NUMBER that does not exist in SQL Server 2000.

Where is this function being called?  and is there any way to amend this (e.g. whenever ROW_NUMBER function is being called, use another FUNCTION instead).